# Reference the same entity by two different entities Ef Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am a bit confused about this, I am implementing a Wish List in which multiple users can add the same entity (Product) to their list.
I extended the identity user class and added an `ICollection<Product>` 
but i cant seem to figure out how can multiple users reference the same product in terms of foreign keys, because whenever a user add a product to their wish list it gets deleted from the previous user as the foreign key now references the new user. obviously my logic is flawed and i misunderstood how the relationship should be defined can you please point me in the right direction?

here is the Product entity

```
    public class Product
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Category")]
        public int SubcategoryFK { get; set; }
        public virtual SubCategory Category { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfItems { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string IsInStock { get; set; }
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
        public string LongDescription { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SalesUser")]
        public string SalesUserFK { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser SalesUser { get; set; }
```

and the relationship is configured like this

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
 .HasMany(a => a.Products)
 .WithOne(p => p.SalesUser).HasForeignKey(z => z.SalesUserFK).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, one user can have multiple products, and one product can be associated with multiple users. This is called a many-to-many relationship. Such relationships are generally modeled by adding an in-between table/entity that represents the relationship. In your case, you might have a ProductUser entity that has a foreign key to Product and User. Both product and users will then have a collection of ProductUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kei commented , the relationship of `Product` and `User` is many-to-many. In EF Core ,[Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#other-relationship-patterns) relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are not yet supported. However, you can represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.

```
public class Product
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int SubcategoryFK { get; set; }
    public virtual SubCategory Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfItems { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string IsInStock { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }

    public List<UserProduct> UserProducts { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
{
    public List<UserProduct> UserProducts { get; set; }
}

public class UserProduct
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public Guid ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProduct>()
            .HasKey(up => new { up.ProductId, up.ApplicationUserId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProduct>()
            .HasOne(up => up.Product)
            .WithMany(p => p.UserProducts)
            .HasForeignKey(up => up.ProductId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProduct>()
            .HasOne(up => up.ApplicationUser)
            .WithMany(au => au.UserProducts)
            .HasForeignKey(up => up.ApplicationUserId);
    }
```

Reference : [Many-to-many relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many) and [Cascade Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete)